# PHPWord and Codeigniter cant locate output file

Tags: codeigniter, phpword

I have followed all the instruction about the installation of PHPWord in Codeigniter [here](http://chanthoeunkim.blogspot.com/2013/05/creating-ms-word-document-using.html)

I just don't know where to locate my output file (filename.docx) and how to know if it is working or not. there is no error message.

here is my code:

> ```
>   $PHPWord = $this->word;
>   $section = $PHPWord->createSection(array('orientation'=>'landscape'));
>   $section->addText('Hello World!');
>   $section->addTextBreak(2);
>
>   $section->addText('I am inline styled.', array('name'=>'Verdana', >'color'=>'006699'));
>   $section->addTextBreak(2);
>
>   $PHPWord->addFontStyle('rStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=>true, >'size'=>16));
>   $PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align'=>'center', >'spaceAfter'=>100));
>   $section->addText('I am styled by two style definitions.', 'rStyle', >'pStyle');
>   $section->addText('I have only a paragraph style definition.', null, >'pStyle');
>
>   $filename='kem.docx'; //save our document as this file name
>   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats->officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); //mime type
>   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell >browser what's the file name
>   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
>
>   $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
>   $objWriter->save('php://output');
> ```

btw, i'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: what is the error? i think it is located on your controller directory.

Comment: there is no error..i can't find any error..i just cant locate my file..i check the controller folder, still no .docx file

Comment: then your script is not generating anything. what does it say when you dump `$objWriter`

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in the code. In all the styling arrays there are extra >s. Maybe just copy&paste errors...

Because you output to php://output no file will be written it will just be sent directly to browser. Instead use something like $objWriter->save('d:\www\' . $filename); to create an output file.

Using the following code all works fine. it will both output to file and send it to browser.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$section = $PHPWord->createSection(array('orientation'=>'landscape'));
$section->addText('Hello World!');
$section->addTextBreak(2);


$section->addText('I am inline styled.', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'color'=>'006699'));
$section->addTextBreak(2);

$PHPWord->addFontStyle('rStyle', array('bold'=>true, 'italic'=>true, 'size'=>16));
$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('pStyle', array('align'=>'center', 'spaceAfter'=>100));
$section->addText('I am styled by two style definitions.', 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
$section->addText('I have only a paragraph style definition.', null, 'pStyle');

$filename='kem.docx'; //save our document as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell >browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$objWriter->save('d:\www\\php\\genDoc\\' . $filename);

/* For Unix / Linux

$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$objWriter->save('/home/ubuntu/workspace/uploads/'. $filename);

*/
?>
```